# Scroll View and Menu

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a Scroll View with a product list, and another Scoll View with the images.

I would like to know how I could pass the images and the other Scroll View with the names will update and change as the images.

So far I've made it:

```
final ScrollView scrol = findViewById ( R.id.scrol );
        scrol.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged() {
                Log.d("TAG", "onScrollChanged: ");

            }
        });
```

Comment: U want to update one scroll view by other?